# What is the alternative to sqlplus command line tool for unixodbc in linux system?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, odbc, unixodbc

I am trying to migrate oracle db to posgresql,and I am using unixODBC to make application db agnostic. UnixODBC provides different drivers for oracle and posgresql to achieve DB agnostic. And it is working very fine on C++ & perl libraries.

But in bash/ksh scripts sqlplus is used to run queries on oracle.
Now for unixODBC based db agnostic approach what is the good alternative to sqlplus to use in these scripts?

Please note:

1. psql from postgresql is not useful as it will defeat the db agnostic purpose
2. isql utility provided by unixODBC is very simple and lacks many features thus not very effective

PS: This question is specific to bash/ksh scripts.

Comment: Postgres and Oracle are two different things. If you think that you can make anything more complicated then `select * from some_table` db agnostic then you are in for a learning experience.  Already it is not as you are using different drivers. You would have more luck using something like [Oracle FDW](http://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/) to create Oracle foreign tables in Postgres.

Comment: About the only thing worse than striving for a db agnostic process is achieving it.  (IMHO) It is a flawed concept. Doing so means you can *only have the lowest common denominator* of the two. Both Oracle and Postgres are advanced systems, often offering the same advanced features.  But the approach to those features are very different, thus requiring you to take a different approach.

Comment: You can try [usql](https://github.com/xo/usql), [DbShell](https://dbschema.com/dbshell.html) or [jdbcsql](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdbcsql/files/?source=navbar)

Comment: "lacks many features"  Isn't that exactly what you signed up for by going the "db agnostic" path?

Comment: I agree with the previous comments regarding lowest common denominator and lack of features. You might want to read something I wrote on the topic of database independence a couple of years ago: https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2019/01/21/database-independence-is-a-myth/ Bottom line is that folks usually invest a lot of money in databases _because_ of all of those features you say you're missing. You give all that up to become "independent", promising to reinvent that feature wheel in the application tier, which is impossible. Databases are _not_ simple storage and should not be used that way.

Comment: Yes..I am aware of disadvantages of db agnostic.
UnixODBC provides different drivers for oracle and posgresql to achieve DB agnostic. And it is working very fine on C++/perl libraries. 
My question is specific to bash/ksh scripts, So If you have any knowledge on that feel free to share that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command isql which can help.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/checking-odbc-connectivity-linux